# Sublime text 3 ugly syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm learning Ruby and I'm using Sublime Text 3 but I find the syntax highlighting really strange.

For example :

[Ugly syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i33td.png)

Even after setting the syntax to ruby.

[Ruby syntax set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ebfF.png)

I'd like to know if this is normal, or if I need to change something on the users
settings or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax file for Ruby ([`Ruby.sublime-syntax`](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/463b400bfbbdc0772a3d6a350a5761a3fb1593c8/Ruby/Ruby.sublime-syntax)) contains a list of unresolved issues. Among them is:

```
      text:
      "p << end
      print me!
      end"
      symptoms:
      not recognized as a heredoc
      solution:
      there is no way to distinguish perfectly between the << operator and the start
      of a heredoc. Currently, we require assignment to recognize a heredoc. More
      refinement is possible.
      • Heredocs with indented terminators (<<-) are always distinguishable, however.
      • Nested heredocs are not really supportable at present
```

So yeah, it's normal.

Answer (score 1):

You could visit https://packagecontrol.io/ and use something like Railscast Colour Scheme

The basic syntax highlighting that comes w/ sublime is pretty sparse - these packages usually do a better job.  Also this is just one example.  There's plenty of themes and color schemes.

To install package control `ctrl+` and past in the snippet according to your version of sublime from this page https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3